# MVC - jQuery could not access to appended partial view which created by Ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a simple partial view which it is called by Ajax and will add to a span on cshtml page by jQuery. Till now, every thing is working perfect.

Create.cshtml

```
<span id="SpanCoverPhoto"></span>
```

myjQuery.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select[id=BusinessList]').before(function () {
        loadCoverPhotos($('select[id=BusinessList]'));
    });

    $('select[id=BusinessList]').change(function () {
        loadCoverPhotos($('select[id=BusinessList]'));
    });

    function loadCoverPhotos(businessList) {

        var id = businessList.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/CoverPhotos/Load",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'BId': id },
            success: function (data) {
                $('span[id=SpanCoverPhoto]').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Cover photos not loaded");
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<banaam.Models.CoverPhoto>

<div>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <div class="Coverphoto">
         <img src="~/Images/BusinessBackground/Thumb_@item.Wallpaper" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-width:120px; max-height:100px;" />
      </div>
    }
</div>
```

Right now, I would like to click on a photo and again handle it by jQuery. But, the append data to the span not shown at "view page source" and just I could see them when I use F12.

Could you please let me know, how could I click the photos and get respond by jQuery?

Best regards and many thanks for your time,

Amin

Comment: Content loaded by AJAX will not be displayed in view page source and Why are you not using ID selector like `$('#SpanCoverPhoto')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a listener on the `document` with jQuery, in order to listen this event on the whole page. Even when new elements are appended.

You can do it like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-class', function(event) {
    console.log('Image clicked!');
});
```

Change .your-class by .img-thumbnail for ex.
And take a look at the doc : http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: Thank you very much. saved my time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events to the items that are loaded after initial page load.

```
$(document).on('.Coverphoto').click(function(){ //your implementation here });
```

Note: You can not see the content of document that are loaded using View Page Source. They are only visible using F12 (Developer Tools)